# Use custom animation queues in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I want to run two different animations queues on the same element, because they can be modified seperately.

I use the standard fx queue for the first one, so I decided to use a custom queue for the second, but the animation does not start.

The jQuery doc says it needs at least jQuery 1.7, and need to manually call `.dequeue()`in case of custom queue, that point's ok.

So, here's my code:

```
var css = {
    'margin-top' : '50px',
    'margin-left' : '50px'
}

$("#myDiv").stop("customQueue").animate(css, {
    duration: 400,
    queue: "customQueue"
}).dequeue("customQueue");
```

which does absolutely nothing (no js error too).

While this works fine (but without animation).

```
var css = {
    'margin-top' : '50px',
    'margin-left' : '50px'
}

$("#myDiv").css(lCss);
```

Do someone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: What I'm trying to do here, is to use the `queue` option of the `jQuery.animate()` function, as described in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), not the `jQuery.queue()` function.

EDIT 2: put @Balint 's modifications

Comment: It isn't the preferred syntax, but it's a totally acceptable one. And it works.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your syntax

```
var css = {
    'margin-top' : "50px",
    'margin-left' : "50px"
}

$("#myDiv").stop("customQueue").animate(css, {
    duration: 400,
    queue: "customQueue"
}).dequeue("customQueue");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7AWtL/1/)

Comment: nope, in my code I use a variable to store the element name, I wrote "myDiv" here for simplicity. I use the same for the second piece of code, and it works fine. Thanks for the quick answer though :)

Comment: I have changed the css object too... you have to put the 50px in `"`, also check the fiddle and be amazed :)

Comment: oops, right, but it's a typo too, as I store in variables too, sorry

Comment: It is still working if you take a look at the jsFiddle link...
So 2 things can be left: wrong placement of the JS code (running before DOM load) or jQuery is not included. Any error messages?

Comment: I get no error messages, jQuery is included and the DOM is loaded, as my second example works fine, and it's placed at same spot in my project.

Comment: You might have to post the exact code&html, as the code in my answer is working, so something must be wrong in your script....

Comment: i checked, the standard fx queue isn't interfering, i get the same issue when I don't use it in parallel.

Comment: but my script is >1000 lines long, I can't post it here entirely :)

Comment: Nope, it isn't that neither, i tested my two examples apart. I thought my problem came from the usage of the function, but it must come from it's usage in project. Thanks for your help, i'll post here when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found what's wrong:

I said I was using the standard fx queue for others effects, but when I interrupt it with `$.stop()` it stop EVERY queue, not only the fx.

So, if like me you're using a custom queue with the standard one, stop the standard queue with `stop("fx")` and not just `stop()`

Thanks everyone for your help.